# Bootstrap navbar must appear from 2nd div

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I would like to hide the navbar from the 1st div and let it appear from the second one... How can I do it?

From the div where is fritten the following string: "DIV 2 NAVBAR MUST APPEAR FROM HERE!!"

[Codepen here](http://codepen.io/paolopolix/pen/LNmxJv)

```
<div>
  <div id="main">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <h2>Div 1: I DON'T WANT NAVBAR HERE!!!</h2>
  </div>

  <div  class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#home">HOME <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#third">LINK</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="home">
      <h1>DIV 2 NAVBAR MUST APPEAR FROM HERE!!</h1>        
    </div>
    <div id="about">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-md-10">
          <h2 class="title">ABOUT</h2>
          <div class="overflow">
          <p>Lorem ipsum goes here.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="third">
      <h2 class="title">SECOND</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved giving `position:relative` to the second div and `position: absolute` to the navbar in that way:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() > $('#main').outerHeight())
    $('.navbar').removeClass('fixed');
else
    $('.navbar').addClass('fixed');
  });
```

---

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.fixed {
  position: absolute;
}
```

[Edited codepen here](http://codepen.io/paolopolix/pen/LNmxJv)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your javascript

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > $('#main').outerHeight()) 
        $('.navbar').show();
    else 
        $('.navbar').hide();
});
```

Comment: It works! But is it possible to set it on the top of the second div (so not hiding it) and then to follow the scroll down?